# Postgres query is getting lock while executing through shell script

Tags: postgresql, ddl

The below query is getting locked by executing through perl

```
ALTER TABLE base_table
   DETACH PARTITION part_table;
```

By using this query

```
  select pid,state, 
       usename, 
       pg_blocking_pids(pid) as blocked_by, 
       query as blocked_query
from pg_stat_activity
where cardinality(pg_blocking_pids(pid)) > 0;
```

```
  pid  | state  | usename  | blocked_by |           blocked_query            
-------+--------+----------+------------+------------------------------------
 20521 | active | parttest | {20306}    |         ALTER TABLE BASE        +
       |        |          |            |    DETACH PARTITION part_table
       |        |          |            | 
(1 row)
```

Can you please suggest me how to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to kill session 20306

Comment: Figure out what 20306 is doing, then either kill it or wait for it.